# How can i logout from my application

Tags: android

I am new to android.
I want in my application logout facility. 
How can i log out from my application. I want to clear shared preferences in logout button ,but i don't know How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. keep `android:noHistory` for all of your activities
2. See that you clear everything in `onDestroy()` or `onStop()` of your root activity